# mysqldump puts CREATE on the first line with mysqldump

Tags: database, bash, mysql

Here's my full bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

logs="$HOME/sitedb_backups/log"

mysql_user="user"
mysql_password="pass"

mysql=/usr/bin/mysql
mysqldump=/usr/bin/mysqldump

tbackups="$HOME/sitedb_backups/today"
ybackups="$HOME/sitedb_backups/yesterday"

echo "`date`" > $logs/backups.log

rm $ybackups/* >> $logs/backups.log
mv $tbackups/* $ybackups/ >> $logs/backups.log

databases=`$mysql --user=$mysql_user -p$mysql_password -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema)"`

for db in $databases ; do
  $mysqldump --force --opt --user=$mysql_user -p$mysql_password --databases $db | gzip > "$tbackups/$db.gz"
  echo -e "\r\nBackup of $db successfull" >> $logs/backups.log
done

mail -s "Your DB backups is ready!" yourmail@gmail.com <<< "Today: "`date`"
DB backups of every site is ready."

exit 0
```

Problem is when i try to import it with mysql i am gettint error 1044 error connecting to oldname_db. When i opened sql file i have noticed on the first line `CREATE` command so it tries to create that database with the old name. How can i solve that problem?

**SOLVED.**

Using `--databases` parameter in my case is not necessary and because of `--databases` it was generating CREATE and USE action in the beginning of the sql file, hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--no-create-db` option of `mysqldump`.

From `man mysqldump`:

> **--no-create-db, -n**
>
> This option suppresses the CREATE DATABASE statements that are
>   otherwise included in the output if the --databases or --all-databases
>   option is given.

Comment: Nice but now i have USE `prefix_olddb`; how can i deal with that also?

Comment: Mmmm I don't know. I got that info from `man mysqldump`. I strongly recommend you to check if further.

Comment: Just found it, when you are using --databases it automatically adds CREATE `db_name` and USE `db_name`. But with --no-create-db i can get rid of CREATE but i cannot remove USE line.